# jQuery .click() only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make some text that changes when you click it, but changes back if you click it again.
It works fine, once. But if i try it a second time, nothing happens.

My HTML:

```
<div id="text">
    <p>TEXT1</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text").click(function(){
        $(this).html("<p>TEXT2</p>").click(function(){
            $(this).html("<p>TEXT1</p>");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Example:
http://mrkireko.github.io/jQueryExample/

Comment: don't bind two click events, just use an if statment that changes it to x if it's y, or y if it's x.

Comment: What are you really trying to do.  This isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: You need to create delegated click events n such.

Answer (score 2):

It's because after the first click, you now have *two* handlers assigned,

The first one still puts the `TEXT2` in place, but the second one changes it back.

One correct solution is to use the handler version of `.toggle()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text").toggle(function(){
        $(this).html("<p>TEXT2</p>");
        return false;
    }, function(){
        $(this).html("<p>TEXT1</p>");
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

As @KevinB noted, this version of `.toggle()` is deprecated. To do your own toggle, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#text").click(function(i){
        return function() {
            $(this).html(++i % 2 ? "<p>TEXT2</p>" : "<p>TEXT1</p>");
            return false;
        };
    }(0));
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/NkGZj/

Comment: Note however that using .toggle as an event binding was deprecated, and later removed from the jquery core.

Comment: Seems ok, but very time I add a `.toggle()` event, the text dissapears.

Comment: @MrKireko: You mean the last example? Sorry, I was supposed to change the event to `click`, and I forgot the modulus. I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest instead:

```
$('#text p').click(function(){
    $(this).text(function(i,t){
        return $.trim(t) === 'text1' ? 'text2' : 'text1';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/azekE/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: The entire `div` is no longer clickable. To take that approach, you'd need to traverse to the `p` from the `div`.

Comment: Well, yes; but: "I am trying to make some text that changes when you click it," Given that the text is within the `p` (and therefore it's the `p` that's going to be clicked), I don't see that as a problem.

Comment: Unless OP is allowing for an oversized click area based on the styling. I mean there must be *some* reason there's a single `p` inside a single `div` with the handler on the `div`, no?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm going from what's explicit in the question. If the OP leaves a comment about a problem with this approach, then I'll try and address it, if that's any help?

Comment: Sure, whatever. Just pointing out that you've altered the meaning of the code. The approach is fine, but to maintain the same meaning, you'd need to bind to `div` and traverse to `p`. That's all I'm saying. I don't know if it's an issue. That's up to OP. But then OP may not notice at first that there was a change. So I figure why introduce potential problems without at least giving a warning that the given code doesn't precisely emulate the original, especially when it's very easy to use emulate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding multiple click handlers to the same element, and they are all executing every time you click. Since the handler to change the text to `TEXT1` executes last, that's what you end up with.

See the `console.log()` output here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tcMx5/

Binding event handlers in event handlers is almost never the right thing to do. Instead, have one handler that checks the current state and toggles the value.

Answer (score 1):

Several answers here, some will work well.  Here is another option, using class:

```
<div id="text" class="state1">
  <p>TEXT1</p>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#text").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('state1')) {
      $this.html('<p>TEXT2</p>');
    }
    else {
      $this.html('<p>TEXT1</p>');
    }
    $this.toggleClass('state1');
  });
});
```

I would lean more towards this solution because it is not dependent on what is actually contained within the element.  Unless, of course, you know that it will never change and you can reliably target the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

> 

```
$( "#text" ).toggle(function() {
  this.html("<p>text 2</p>");
}, function() {
    this.html("<p>text 1</p>");
});
```

Comment: Note however that using .toggle as an event binding was deprecated, and later removed from the jquery core.

Comment: `this.html()` won't work because `this` is not a jQuery object.